# How to Change Order Id in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I did my website using `Opencart`.I want to change my Order ID to this format: 
`ID: XY-MM-DD-YYYY-0001`.

I searched in google but i didn't get correct answer. Please any one tell me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for replying my question Jay Gilford.could you please tell me the reason,why it's not possible?

Comment: Please Read this. Hope, Helpfully for you. http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=6880